# AX 2012 with managed code - How do you return a value from .Net code?

Tags: .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm new to Dynamics AX 2012 development and am using a C# dll to handle the "heavy lifting".

I'm basically understanding how to delegate or trigger a C# *void* method and to use parameters passed in to it using the *xppPrePostArgs* object.

However I can't find any discussion or examples on how to pass values back out again (either by a return value or setting the *setReturnValue*  method of the args object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XppPrePostArgs` parameter is used in event handlers.

[How to Modify Parameter Values in a Pre-Method Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg862568.aspx).

[How to Modify the Return Value in an Post-Method Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg843664.aspx).